# Should the answer threshold for forcing community wiki be decreased on SO?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

In wake of SUs lower threshold of posts for a community wiki switch.

Should SO follow suit, what is the magic number?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193551
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783238
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230218
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940

Etc ...

Comment: How is this working for you when you come across answers that have 10+ variations on a theme for simple questions? Like that SQL question you tried cleaning up some time ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not until we have at least a month of data under the SU change to see how it's going to pan out.

Comment: can I mark this as correct?

Comment: @Sam:  I would!  No better answer than the person that's running the site!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't take too many edits right now to switch it.

Answer (score 0):

No, IMHO CW is there basically to stop rep whoring on fun questions, not to disincentivize answering questions that a lot of people find interesting.

Comment: I agree with this. I was against lowering the answer threshold on CW, but it looks like I was overruled. I would have only favored a lower automatic threshold if there was also a way in place to flip questions BACK in case of mistaken flips.